# To Add huge set of secs.milllisec to given time in hh:mm:ss.millisecs

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Start time is  10:48:00.000
(10 - hr
48 - min
00 - secs
000 - milli secs).
Requirement to add huge set of secs.milli secs to the start time
Eg: 01.408
(01 - secs
408 - milli secs).
(Start time) 10:48:00.000 + 01.408 (secs.milli secs) = 10:48:01.408.
To Take care:
1. 60 secs  is  1 min, so minutes needs to get incremented accordingly,
Eg:(Start time) 10:48:00.000 + 61.523 (secs.milli secs) = 10:49:01.523
2. 60 minutes is  1 hr, so hours needs to get incremented accordingly,
Eg:(Start time) 10:48:00.000 + 3600.478 (secs.milli secs) = 11:48:00.478
Need help to derive the formula  / steps  to achieve in Microsoft excel.

Answer (score 0):

If **C1** contains a time like:

```
02:57:46.667
```

and **D1** contains an integer like *123*, representing 123 milliseconds.  Then in **E1** enter:

```
=C1+D1/(24*60*60*1000)
```

to sum them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Since, to add with secs.millisecs (set as number in Format cells), modified the formula as C1+D1/(24*60*60) which worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Added h:mm:ss.000 + secs.millisecs(set as number in Format cells) to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcUlC.jpg)